# Node-Inspector issues on Vagrant

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant

Trying to install **node-inspector** via `npm install` and getting this issue https://gist.github.com/dbclkclk/dc16ebbfddd346bfcdabb2f2fb2ad182.

The installation is happening on Vagrant however, it's complaining about incompatible linux distro.

Thanks.

Comment: can you copy your Vagrantfile see how you're doing the install

Comment: @FrédéricHenri this error doesn't happen during provision but, inside in the Vagrant box itself `vagrant ssh`. Either way, attached is my VagrantFile https://gist.github.com/dbclkclk/ed2389d700fca713d733674b712255b4